# Load line analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

[image]

You are to design a network of resistors to be used in the circuit, such that i<sub>D</sub> = 1 mA when the diode is connected, and v<sub>S</sub> = 2 V when the diode is disconnected.

Normally questions like this would only have one resistor in series with the diode. Then, I would easily be able to draw the load line using the KVL equation. In this question, does the circuit indicate that the resistor network is connected in parallel? And if the switch near where i<sub>D</sub> written is off, or when the diode is disconnected, how can v<sub>S</sub> be 2V even though the battery provided 6V? I do not understand the second design constraint. Also, when i<sub>D</sub> is 1mA as the question says, v<sub>D</sub> is 0.9V according to the graph, which is I'm assuming to be the operating point, right?

Comment: This is pretty much an exact repeat [of your earlier and now self-deleted question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/628872/load-line-and-diode?noredirect=1#628872). It was closed because you needed to have shown effort in solving this your self = this is how this site deals with homework questions.

Comment: Since this is homework we won't just give you the answer. We expect you to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself. Show us all of your work, then ask a **specific** question.

Comment: @Antonio51 the diode has a forward volt drop at 1 mA so it's not as simple as you imply.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson
I've changed my questions to be more specific. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

I'm just giving hints since this is homework. Plotting the load line requires knowledge of two points on the line. That is, you must know the values of \$i_D\$ and \$v_S\$ for two different conditions.

In this case, the two conditions are when the switch is open and when it is closed. I think you know the values of current and voltage for those two cases, so just plot those two points and draw a line through them.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote 1 min ago.

Comment: @MissMulan No, what I wrote is not the same. You assumed that Rth could be calculated a priori but the content of the "resistor network" is not known. Your approach will not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did with a 1N4007GP. EE&O.

Draw load line ... as stated in picture. Calculate Rth (-> R1).
Assume that network is a two resistor attenuator.
NB: It is quasi obvious that it is this configuration because of the voltage (**2V** open diode path).
So attenuator is a 2R-R network (\$ 2V = 6V * R/(R+2R) \$).
Rthevenin = R * 2R / (R+2R) = 2/3*R.

[image]

Calculate then resistors R2 & R3 (or R4 & R5) in my picture.
R1 & R2 in Maple sheet.

[image]

Report in simulator, DC Analysis.

[image]

Case of OP picture ... Draw load line ... Rth = 2 / 1.85mA = 1081 Ohm.
(Should be obviously 1100 Ohm).
So resistors are 1621 Ohm and 3243 Ohm.
Sorry for the resistors labels which are not the same in the simulator and in the Maple sheet.

[image]

Comment: I would never DV this effort, but did you check your current If and Rth for voltage drop?

Comment: One part of the picture (D1) is for the drawing of the characteristic of the diode and the Load Line. So you can read that the current of D1 is 11.374 A. So, also for the current of V1 ... current which are irrelevant for the other currents parts. I should have "separate" this part of this circuit (higher left part in picture).

Comment: Remember also that it for a "real" diode 1N4007. The values to be used in OP pictures are in the lower Maple sheet ... 1621 Ohm and 3243 Ohm. Rth is in fact really 1.1 / 1mA=1100 Ohms (I used 1081, because of interpolating in the picture). Really, No need for calculating with Load Line. But as it is the "tool" generally used for solving QP, I used it. No need de facto for the OP characteristic.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I would only say that quasi all my "answer" is a "way" for solving the OP question. I did not do the work he has to do.

Comment: +1 for analysis using theory rather than plot  .  1621 is pretty close to 1650 for this very weak diode

Answer (score 0):

Given diode forward current (If) and open circuit (oc) conditions with diode VI curve:

Vbat = 6 V
If = 1 mA
Voc = 2 V

### Calc. using a simple Thevenin network.

1. From plot Vf= 0.9V @ 1mA = 900 Ohm equivalent resistance (at 1 mA only)
2. Given with diode off Voc=Vth=2V  or 1/3 of the battery voltage so the series = R1= 2R2 (R2=shunt) so R1 will supply the 1mA to D1 and additional current through R2 such that ;

- I1*R1=5.1V with Diode on I1 = I2+If(=1mA) and
- I2*R2 = 0.9V

3. Solve for R1, R2 using Thevenin Equivalents

[image]

### Design Verification Test (DVT)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMurw3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

DVT

Plug values back into design rules to verify.
Do a Thevenin load line

[image]

Comment: I thought the policy here was to not do anyone's homework for them.

Comment: yes but after seeing so many errors, ....I just had to introduce the concept of DVT which is critical for all designs, no matter how simple. Besides a load line is not needed here and may lead to errors. So I'll delete it now

Answer (score -1):

If the network is only made of linear components it can be replaced by a thevenin voltage and a thevenin resistance.In order to find the point of operation of the diode mark the points(Vth/Rth,0) and (0,Vth).Then draw the straight line starting from (Vth/Rth,0) and ending at (0,Vth).The point of operation of the diode will be where that line intersects with the IV curve of the diode.

Comment: It's the other way around. You take the known diode load line and solve the unknown resistor network based on that.

Comment: I simply read the plot of Vf=0.9V @ 1mA given and computed Rth for a 5.1V drop

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75  for a 1.1V voltage drop? Eth = 2V...

Comment: yes for the Thevenin equiv . that works too and is much simpler @Antonio51  The diode load line is not used , rather the Thevenin load line so just the intersection of 0.9V,1mA and 2V,Rth. Thus Miss Mulan is also correct in this approach FWIW as shown in my answer, although more awkward as I rotated to show positive R slopes

Answer (score -1):

> Well, let's make a mathematical closed solution. I know that this is maybe above the OP's knowledge, but I think it is important to show it in combination with the other answers given.

The [Shockley diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation), gives the relation between the voltage across and the current through a diode:

$$\text{I}_\text{D}=\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\text{V}_\text{D}}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)\tag1$$

Where \$\text{I}_\text{D}\$ is the diode current, \$\text{I}_\text{S}\$ is the reverse bias [saturation current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_current), \$\text{V}_\text{D}\$ is the voltage across the diode, \$\text{q}\$ is the [electron charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge), \$\text{k}\$ is the [Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant), \$\text{T}\$ is the temperature and \$\eta\$ is the ideality factor.

---

Let's do an example. We are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnmuMs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\tag2$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\text{V}_1}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Substitute \$(3)\$ into \$(2)\$, in order to get:

$$\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\text{V}_1}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)\tag4$$

For the LED, let's use parameters taken from a Luminus PT-121-B LED: \$\eta=8.37\$, and \$\text{I}_\text{S}=435.2\:\text{nA}\$ (with \$\text{V}_\text{T}:=\frac{\text{kT}}{\text{q}}=\frac{8094745087}{320435326800}\approx0.0252617\:\text{V}\$, of course).

Without the diode we know that we can write:

$$\text{V}_{1\space|\space\text{D}\space=\space0}=\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}\tag5$$

So, using the things we know we can solve:

$$
\begin{cases}
2=\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\cdot6\\
\\
10^{-3}=\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\text{V}_1}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)
\end{cases}\tag6
$$

And find:

$$\text{R}_1=6000-\frac{2258433879273 \ln \left(\frac{78159}{34}\right)}{3560392520}\tag7$$
$$\text{R}_2=3000-\frac{2258433879273 \ln \left(\frac{78159}{34}\right)}{7120785040}\tag8$$

Which is:

$$\text{R}_1\approx1090.26\space\Omega\space\wedge\space\text{R}_2\approx545.131\space\Omega\tag9$$

---

I solved for all the knowns using [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). The code is given below.

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
q = ((1602176634/(10^9)))*10^(-19);
k = ((1380649/(10^6)))*10^(-23);
T = 20 + ((5463)/20);
Is = (4352/10)*10^(-9);
Vi = 6;
V = 2;
I3 = 10^(-3);
\[Eta] = 837/100;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, 
   I3 == (Is*(Exp[(q*V1)/(\[Eta]*k*T)] - 1)), V == (R2/(R2 + R1))*Vi, 
   I1 > 0 && I2 > 0 && V1 > 0 && R1 > 0 && R2 > 0}, {I1, I2, V1, R1, 
   R2}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> 1/3000 + 1/(1500 - (2258433879273 Log[78159/34])/14241570080),
   I2 -> -(1/1500) + 1/(
    1500 - (2258433879273 Log[78159/34])/14241570080), 
  V1 -> (752811293091 Log[78159/34])/3560392520000, 
  R1 -> 6000 - (2258433879273 Log[78159/34])/3560392520, 
  R2 -> 3000 - (2258433879273 Log[78159/34])/7120785040}}

In[2]:=N[%1]

Out[2]={{I1 -> 0.00400218, I2 -> 0.00300218, V1 -> 1.63658, R1 -> 1090.26, 
  R2 -> 545.131}}
```

---

**EDIT**, I solved for a general formula:

$$\text{R}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{I}_3}\cdot\left(1+\frac{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}{\text{q}\text{V}_{1\space|\space\text{D}\space=\space0}}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{\text{I}_\text{S}}{\text{I}_\text{S}+\text{I}_3}\right)\right)\tag{10}$$
$$\text{R}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{I}_3\left(\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_{1\space|\space\text{D}\space=\space0}\right)}\cdot\left(\text{V}_{1\space|\space\text{D}\space=\space0}+\frac{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}{\text{q}}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{\text{I}_\text{S}}{\text{I}_\text{S}+\text{I}_3}\right)\right)\tag{11}$$

Comment: Ok. These values are for a LED. I would know the results for a simple diode to confirm. Thanks.

Comment: @Antonio51 well, when for example \$\eta=1\$ and \$\text{I}_\text{s}=10^{-6}\$ we get \$\text{R}_1\approx5476.42\space\Omega\$ and \$\text{R}_2\approx2738.21\space\Omega\$.

Comment: Ok. I am trying to solve also with Syrup in Maple ... (diode non-linear classical case). Will add in answer.

Comment: @Antonio51 I provided closed-form formula's to find the resistor values.

Comment: This is undoubtly correct in itsemf but far too advanced to be a good example for a simple basic homework task. There's no need for a Shockley diode formula here at all. All you need to do is to draw the load line as the diode curve is a given and based on that just calculate a couple of resistances.

Comment: @Justme It's even simpler than drawing a load line. Just read the Vf =0.9V at 1mA

Comment: Jan did you verify your voltage drop? Rth=1825 x 1mA = 5.1V not

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 If the homework task is to use the load line, there's little we can do about it. Besides the line will help to understand the open and short circuit voltages which also help in determining the resistances.